# Python iterator as class member?

Tags: python, inheritance, python-2.7, iterator

I have a scheme like:

```
class Base(object):
    param, d=0, 1
    def get_all(self):
        while True:
            a = self.get_xxx(param)
            if not a:
                break
            handle(a)
            param += d

class A(Base):
    def get_xxx(param):
        return some_method(param)

class B(Base):
    def get_xxx(param):
        return other_method(param)
```

Then, I was informed that for B, after each get_xxx param should be a+1 instead of param+d. That means I need to extract the param change logic at the end of get_all. I came up with a scheme using iterator:

```
class Base(object):
    def get_all(self):
        get_xxx = self.get_xxx()
        while True:
            a = get_xxx.next()
            if not a:
                break
            handle(a)

class A(Base):
    def get_xxx():
        param, d = 0, 1
        while True:
            yield somemethod(param)
            param += d

class B(Base):
    def get_xxx():
        param = 0
        while True:
            a = somemethod(param)
            param = a + 1
            yield a
```

Problem solved, but somehow I feel uncomfortable. So I wonder if there's a better solution? Many thanks!

Comment: Which Python version is this?

Comment: Before beaten to death by the StackOverflow mob, I suggest you take your question to CodeReview : StackOverflow is for technical problem (e.g. "my dog has eaten my program !"), while CodeReview is for improving an existing solution. link : http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ha. thanks @georgesl, didn't know this site before...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make things like `param` and `d` instance attributes:

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.param = 0
        self.d = 1
```

then you don't have to pass anything explicitly into `get_xxx()`. You could replace

```
param += d
```

with

```
self.iterate_param(a):
```

in `Base.get_all()` then define `iterate_param()` appropriately in your two subclasses, i.e.

```
class A(Base):
    ...
    def iterate_param(self, a):
        self.param += self.d

class B(Base):
    ...
    def iterate_param(self, a):
        self.param = a + 1
```